# Use the Squeeze Theorem To Show that $\lim_{ x\to 0} (x^2 \cos20\ pi x) = 0$

Tags: calculus

Use the Squeeze Theorem To Show that $\lim_{ x\to 0} (x^2 \cos20\pi x) = 0$. Illustrate by graphing the functions $f(x) = -x^2$, $g(x) =x^2 \cos20\pi x$, and $h(x) = x^2$ on the same screen.

How would I do this on a Casio fx-9750GII?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$ | \cos \alpha | \leq 1 $$

for any $\alpha $.

In particular, we have

$$ -x^2 \leq x^2 \cos \alpha \leq x^2 $$

Answer (score 0):

In other way:

$0\le |x^2\cos \alpha|\le x^2$ and notice that $x^2\to 0$ as $x\to 0$.

Comment: Well g(x) and h(x) do not have the same numbers, thus, you can not make a determination?